# SBT: Using code from one project in build process of another

Tags: scala, sbt, build-process, multi-project

I have a multi-project build with, say, projects A and B (example of build.sbt in root):

```
lazy val projectA = (project in file("A"))
lazy val projectB = (project in file("B"))
```

I would like to use code from projectA to generate some .java files and put them in projectB, as part of projectB's build process, before the compile step runs for projectB. I have a Scala object for this purpose in projectA. In essence, I have a compiler in projectA that produces files that need to be in projectB *before* it runs the compile step. I've tried the following:

1) Make projectB depend on projectA:

```
lazy val projectB = (project in file("B")) dependsOn(projectA):
```

2) Create projectB/project/Build.scala where-in I define a Task:

```
import projectA.somePackage.ourObject
val myTask = taskKey[Unit]("runs before compilation")

myTask := {
    ourObject.thatMethod()
}

(compile in Compile) <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn(myTask)
```

However, I cannot import things from projectA in this file. I'm probably trying to do this in the wrong way, but I cannot find any tutorials or examples showing me how to do this :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't a complete answer, but it should be more readable than a comment:

Since SBT is recursive, `projectB/project` is itself an SBT project which could depend on `projectA` (add `projectB/project/project/Build.scala` or `projectB/project/build.sbt` correspondingly). Not sure if this will work.

I think the correct approach would be to make `projectB:compile` depend on `projectA:run`, something like

```
(compile in (projectB, Compile)) <<= (compile in (projectB, Compile)).dependsOn(run in (projectA, Compile))
```

If the object you need to use isn't the default one used by `run`, add a new task in `projectA` for running the code generation specifically.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - Unfortunately, I really can't get this to work in any way, shape or form. I just don't understand SBT well enough, I think, and I can't find *any* examples to go off.